# ERROR: Option network must be one of: required! You passed "<IP>" What is the cause of this?

Tags: chef-infra, nfs, chef-recipe, lwrp

I am getting a really strange error while using the **add_exports** LWRP from https://github.com/atomic-penguin/cookbook-nfs

The Strange thing is- it was working perfectly a while back , and the code hasnt been changed.
What could be the cause of this?

```
================================================================================[0m
    serverIP [31mRecipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/nfs/recipes/add_exports.rb[0m
    serverIP ================================================================================[0m
    serverIP 
    serverIP [0mChef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed[0m
    serverIP ----------------------------------[0m
    serverIP Option network must be one of: required!  You passed "10.71.118.68".[0m
    serverIP 
    serverIP [0mCookbook Trace:[0m
    serverIP ---------------[0m
    serverIP   /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/nfs/recipes/add_exports.rb:4:in `block in from_file'
    serverIP [0m  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/nfs/recipes/add_exports.rb:2:in `from_file'[0m
    serverIP 
    serverIP [0mRelevant File Content:[0m
    serverIP ----------------------[0m
    serverIP /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/nfs/recipes/add_exports.rb:
    serverIP [0m
    serverIP [0m  1:  # Adds an entry in /etc/exports on nfs server
    serverIP [0m  2:  nfs_export "/exports" do
    serverIP [0m  3:    directory node['nfs']['exports']['directory']
    serverIP [0m  4>>   network node['nfs']['exports']['network']
    serverIP [0m  5:    writeable node['nfs']['exports']['writeable']
    serverIP [0m  6:    sync node['nfs']['exports']['sync']
    serverIP [0m  7:    options node['nfs']['exports']['options']
    serverIP [0m  8:  end  9:  [0m
    serverIP 
    serverIP [0m[0m
    serverIP Running handlers:[0m
    serverIP [2015-10-09T01:29:11-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
    serverIP Running handlers complete
    serverIP [0m[2015-10-09T01:29:11-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
    serverIP Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 05 seconds[0m
    serverIP [2015-10-09T01:29:11-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
    serverIP [2015-10-09T01:29:11-05:00] ERROR: Option network must be one of: required!  You passed "10.71.118.68".
    serverIP [2015-10-09T01:29:12-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my bad! This is an issue related to the change in the version of Chef server to 
**version 12.5.1**  This is the relevant pull (done promptly by davidgiesberg :D )that fixes this.  https://github.com/atomic-penguin/cookbook-nfs/pull/67